# Android HTML input field correction/completion is awful

Tags: android, html, chrome-for-android

Try this on a modern (ICS, Jelly bean) Android device:

1. Open the Messaging app and type a sentence to someone. The keyboard is snappy, the completion works well, and spaces are added after words are completed.
2. Open `www.google.com` in the browser or Chrome for Android and type the same sentence in the search field. It sucks. The completion is awful, the correction doesn't work (it *suggests* corrections but never choose them automatically), and spaces aren't inserted after words.

What's the deal? Is there any way I can improve the completion correction on my HTML pages, maybe by adding some hidden attributes to the `<input>` elements?

Comment: The correction depends on the input method the end user is using. This is customisable.